# Choosing tools for telegram message forwarding bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to write a telegram bot in python to send messages from one channel to another by keywords. I have a problem. To write a bot and set the search parameters in the `JSON file` (search channel, send channel and keywords), I used the `telebot` library, but I did not find a method for parsing and sending messages in it. For parsing and forwarding, I created a module with the `telethon` library (`TelegramClient`), but I was unable to create a bot in it. As a result, I first need to run the bot to set the parameters, and then the client for parsing and forwarding. As a result, the question is: is there a library for python with a telegram API, with which you can write a bot with methods for parsing and sending messages?

Also tried the `AIOGram` and `python-telegram-bot` libraries but ran into the above problem.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't ment for software recommendations, consider reading [ask].